# Azure DevOps CI/CD to plesk server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an ASP.NET Core web API and I'm using Azure DevOps. All deploys are made by Visual Studio to a .NET plesk server. I download the publishsettings file and imported in VS.

```
<publishData>
    <publishProfile
        profileName="xxx - Web Deploy"
        publishMethod="MSDeploy"
        publishUrl="https://xxx:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=xxx"
        msdeploySite="xxx" userName="xxx"
        destinationAppUrl="http://xxx"
        controlPanelLink="https://xxx:8443"/>
</publishData>
```

Now I created a pipeline to automate this process. This pipeline, generates the artifact.

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish'
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    zipAfterPublish: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

I don't know how can I deploy to server? I created a Release and I tried to upload the artifact, but always stops beacause some file is in use. I tried Azure App Service Deploy but gaves me an error (my server is not azure btw).

[image]

[image]

Any help to improve my development process?

Comment: Did you do any research on how to deploy using a `publishsettings` file? Using the step specifically designed for deploying to an Azure App Service is *definitely* not going to work for something that's not an Azure App Service. I can't imagine why you thought it might.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, yes, and you're right. Do you have any tip how to deploy?